# c# DataGridView Add Images Per Row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a GUI Which Loads data from a File in order to fill my DataGridView will data. I have two DataGridViews. One for Teams and one for Members. When i Click on a different Team it shows me the members associated with that team.

I want to be a able to add a Image in for the team so TeamLogo for example. I have added the column already and made it a DataGridViewImageColumn. But when i add a image by using:

```
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Images\ManU.jpeg");
        Team_Logo.Image = image;
```

it adds the same image for all the teams is there a way in order to add separate images and more likely add a OpenFileDialog in order to locate the image my self.

I wouldn't mind if i couldn't do it by column and i had to have a PictureBox as long as Every time i change the Team the Different Image appears.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need to do is to load each value separately for each row.

Here is an example:

First I create a column, add it and give it a Name:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
int icIndex = dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imgCol);
dataGridView1.Columns[icIndex].Name = "Image";
```

Now I set the values for all rows. I use an `ImageList`, which is nice as it be fast and will make sure to get all images of the same size.

Of course you will need to load the right images. You may want to access them by the `imageList1.Images.Keys` collection..

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     if (row.Index < imageList1.Images.Count)    // *
        row.Cells["Image"].Value = imageList1.Images[row.Index];
```

Now each row will show a different image.

Depending on your SelectionMode something like this will show the Image in a PictureBox:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index];
}
```

But you may want to show the `Image` in the `PB` larger than in the `DGV` rows? For this you can either use a **second** `ImageList` with a larger `ImageSize` (up to 256x256 only) or load the images from disk, using the `Images.Key` property..

**Update**

note that the code above uses a simplistic and rather fragile relation to combine the Images to the rows, relying that they are both complete and in the same order.

This should work for testing the user interface but after that you should exchange it for something more robust.

I have added a check (*) but this will only prevent the IndexOutOfRange error when you have less images than rows..

One idea could be to relate the team names with the image names. Not knowing your naming schemes I can't provide code..

And if you want the whole to be editable you need to think about how and where you will store your data. But these question go beyond the scope of the original question..

Comment: in my Form1_Load i have put the code you have provided expect for for the method which is separate. I've added an image to the imagelist by using                             imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Images\Liverpool.jpg")); However i get the following error:         An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: Of course you need to make sure that you have one image in the list for every row you show. With only one image you can only show this one image in the 1st row. The next row, with index=1 will throw the SO exception. You can add checks to prevent that but eventually I'd expect you to show one logo for each team, right? If you want your check can test to see if a suitable image is found and if not load a default image, best put to index 0..

Comment: I have 3 teams so i have added 3 images to the list but now I'm getting the same error but 'InvalidArgument=Value of '3' is not valid for 'index'.' ]

Comment: Indices are zero-based, so for 3 rows and 3 images they should go from 0-2. But you probably have an empty (4th) row at the bottom? Switch that off by setting AllowUserToAddRows to false for theDGV!

Comment: What about if i want to be able to add row to the dataGrid, can't I implement a OpenFileDialog so the user can choose the image?

Comment: or is it not possible?

Comment: Well you can. You can add to the IamgeList at runtime. But a): You should think about how you will store your data and b) you should add a check to prevent any crashes.  You also should replace the rather flimsy relation of rowIndex==imgIndex I used by something more robust..

Comment: i see what you mean, there is no where to really store the images. How would i work it so i can still add more rows?

Comment: I have added a small check that will prevent the crash. But without knowing where to store your data it doesn't make much sense to create them; so that should be next on your list.. Btw, you don't need to store images, usually the names will do.